# Right way to pass input data to blade template in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, input, laravel-4

Is there any difference when i am passing POST data to blade template, between this :

```
Route::post('postpage', function()
{
    return View::make('postdata')->with('postData', Input::all());
});
```

and this one?

```
Route::post('postpage', function()
{
    return View::make('postdata', array('postData'=> Input::all()));
});
```

Or both are the same and i should go on with shorter syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has already been said both will do the same. The difference is, that by chaining methods to the `View` object you will be able to instantiate and manipulate a `View` object while chaining data to it, before it will be eventually returned as response. *In real life that happens pretty rarely, so that for the most purposes both will achieve the same*.

But for passing Input data back to the view there is an even simpler method:

```
return View::make('postdata')->withInput();
```

By using [`withInput()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#old-input) all your previous Input will be passed to the view again.
You would then access it by using `Input::old('email')` in your View for example.

*Make sure that you call `Input::flash()` in your controller method first before using `withInput()`. `Input::old()` pulls data out of the Session Flashdata which makes the call to the mentioned method necessary.* - Thanks to [pc-shooter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387233/pc-shooter) for mentioning.

Comment: For using `Input::old('email')`, you need to do `Input::flash()` in the corresponding controller

Comment: Oops. Totally forgot about that. I'll add it to the answer as soon as I'm on a PC tomorrow. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They are both exactly the same.

Choose whichever one you like most.

Note that you can also pass an array to `with` if you so desire:

```
return View::make('postdata')->with([
    'postData' => Input::all(),
]);
```

In this particular case it wouldn't make much sense, but when passing a lot of data you might like it this way. It is ultimately up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Magic Methods

```
Route::post('postpage', function()
{
    return View::make('postdata')->withPostdata(Input::all());
});
```

$postdata would be accessible from the view